# Django or web to py for e-commerce & a normal website

Tags: django, web, python-3.x, web.py

I have to build an **e-commerce website** for a shopping system and a **Content Management System website** for a college.

I have to chose either Django or web to py with **Python 3.x** and for the backend I am using **Oracle 11g**. I can't understand which one to use, which could be an easier
solution to go with for
an e-commerce website and a simple CMS.

Also, where can I find good tutorials for web to py & Django??

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for Django as I haven't used web.py, however Django only supports python 2.x at this stage so you would need to determine whether or not that violates the requirements of your project.

(There is experimental support for 3.x, but it's not made it into a stable release yet: https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2012/aug/19/experimental-python-3-support/)

That being said, Django is a fantastic framework to work with, and I would give it my whole hearted recommendation if you can put aside the python 3.x compatibility issue. The Django ORM also has support for the version of Oracle that you're using which is a bonus.

The official django tutorial is a great place to start - please see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/#first-steps